# Looking for a variable inside another programs memory

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find an `int` value inside another program's memory (my own little `c++` that only holds that variable). The value is **1234**, but I can't seem to find it.

This is what I'm doing:

```
for (uint adr = 0x00000000; adr <= 0x7FFFFFFF; adr += 1)
{
    // we want status...
    uint progress = (adr*100) / 0x7FFFFFFF;
    Console.WriteLine("Progress: {0} %", progress);

    // look for the int
    IntPtr bytes;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4];

    ReadProcessMemory(process, adr, buffer, 4, out bytes);

    if (BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0) == 1234)
    {
        // we found it...
    }
}
```

There are several errors:

1. The progress does not work.
2. I never get a hit on found.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Maybe this value `1234` is saved in
   `2` byte value not `4` byte.
2. Check readprocess memory not throw you error because you not [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
3. Try big endian reading too, then try reverse bits before reading.

Comment: But the loop looks OK? I did mention that progress is always 0

Comment: @Jason94: Loop is ok, progress is always 0 because you saving value to uint, you should use double.

Comment: @Svisstack: do you mean double progress = (adr*100) / 0x7FFFFFFF; I'm kinda lost in bits and bytes right now :P

Comment: @Jason94: i mean double progress = (((double)adr)*100) / 0x7FFFFFFF;

Comment: @Svisstack: thanks for the correction. But with adr++ it takes me ages to get even 1%! is the stop value, 0x7FFFFFFF, valid? In processlist the app takes up 388kB if that helps.

Comment: @Jason94: you should before ReadProcessMemory call IsReadPtr or something like this i dont remember correctly fucntion name

Answer (score 0):

You can compare results from your program with output of some advanced memory scanner, such as [cheatengine](http://www.cheatengine.org/).